# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended -

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g

```
 public void updateweeks(string getdate)
{
    string result = getdate.Substring(0, 10);
    OracleConnection con;
    OracleCommand cmd;
    con = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString);
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MO_T_WEEK_REPORT SET C_ISACTIVE ='N' where TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(C_DATE,'DD/MM/YY hh24:mi:ss'),'DD/MM/YY')=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('"+result+"','DD/MM/YY hh24:mi:ss'),'DD/MM/YY');";
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();                                          
}
```

In the above code to raise the Exception for "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove semi-colon at the end of the `cmd.CommandText`, here:

```
M/YY');";
      ^
      |
     here
```